# How to store a single array value into a session variable?

Tags: external-scripts

I have

```
Array ( [0] => cid [1] => TN201501HP )
```

Now I want to store "TN201501HP" into some session variable. How to store this value to a session variable?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! How to save a single index of an array in the session is a plain PHP question: `$array = array('cid', 'TN201501HP'); $_SESSION['TN201501HP'] = $array[1];`. If you were to ask how to access Drupal session from an external script, that could be a on-topic question, even I think it was already asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you store array(object) in variable use [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) function. and unserialized [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)
So

```
session_start();
$arr=array(0 => cid ,1 => TN201501HP);
$_SESSION['myvar'] =serialize($arr);
$myarr= unserialize($_SESSION['myvar']);
echo $myarr[1];
```

and if you only want one variable in array try

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['myvar'] = $array[1];
echo $_SESSION['myvar'];
```

Comment: I think that he want only one var

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
//If you want store the value in a session, you need first start the session
session_start();
//I suposse that your array is named $array,
//then if you want get the position 1 use the following line
$_SESSION['var'] = $array[1];
//checking the stored value
echo $_SESSION['var'];

?>
```

Output:

> TN201501HP